# Do Firebase Rule's Order Matter with an Or operator

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm creating a Firebase Database and settings access rules. For a location I have the following rule:

`".write": "data.hasChild(auth.uid) || !data.exists()"`

When I try to write to a test location in the simulator which does NOT exist I get denied, however when I switch the order as below

`".write": "!data.exists() || data.hasChild(auth.uid)"`

It succeeds. Why is this? I see no mentioning of the order in the documentation and I have never seen an Or operator which fails based solely on the first operand.

Comment: The order should not matter. Can you edit your question to include a screenshot of the emulator behaving unexpectedly? I'd like to see the existing JSON, the location you're writing to, the data you're writing and the authentication state.

Comment: I have since modified the original location but I recreated the scenario and tried again but it worked. I think I was misunderstanding how the sent dictionary would be placed in the tree from the simulator and therefore how the rule would be enforced. 

I wish the simulator would show how the data would look after the simulated write.